# Automatically remove files from static library

Tags: c, makefile, unix-ar

I am wondering if it is possible to setup a makefile rule so as to automatically remove object files which are no longer present in the library without having to do a clean build. I have my makefile setup like this.

```
SRC_FILES = a.c b.c c.c

libtest.a : $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
    ar -rcs $@ $?

%.o : %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

Now suppose i remove `c.c` from `SRC_FILES`, I want the next make run to delete the corresponding object file from the archive. Is there any way to do this without having to run a clean build? Deleting the archive first and then rebuilding it doesn't work since the rule is never invoked when the library is more recent than all its dependencies. I also don't wanna rebuild the library if nothing actually changed, so making it a .PHONY wont work either.

Comment: Rebuilding the library is extremely cheap (basically, the object files are concatenated and an index is generated). Are you sure this is inacceptable?

Comment: The problem is, the rule to rebuild the library is never invoked since the library is more recent than all its objects. Suppose I remove c.c, then the library depends on a.o and b.o, both of which are older than the library.

Comment: You can manually remove the library with `rm libtest.a` and then regenerate it if you want.

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835722/relink-makefile-target-when-list-of-dependencies-changes ?

Comment: I didn't ask for 'manually'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing automatic or built-in that you can do. `make` just isn't very good at noticing this sort of thing. The simplest thing you can do that would "solve" this problem would be to keep a [`FORCE`d](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets) target that contains a list of the source files represented in the archive, include that file as a prerequisite of `libtest.a` and compare the contents of the file against the contents of the archive and rebuild/add/delete/etc. to/from the library as appropriate.

```
libtest.lst: FORCE $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
        printf '%s\\n' $(filter-out $<,$^) > $@

libtest.a: libtest.lst $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
        ar t $@ > $@.contents
        if diff -q $@.contents libtest.lst; then \
            ar ....; \
        fi
        rm $@.contents
```

Or if you don't care about avoiding the rebuilding forget the listing/diffing/etc. and just re-run the `ar` command to build the archive.

As an additional improvement you could add the diffing logic to the `libtest.lst` recipe instead so that it only updates the `libtest.lst` file if it changes (to avoid `make` thinking it needs to run the `libtest.a` rule when the library contents haven't changed). Something like this.

```
libtest.lst: FORCE $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
        printf '%s\\n' $(filter-out $<,$^) | sort > $@.tmp
        cmp -s $@ $@.tmp || mv $@.tmp $@
        rm -f $@.tmp

libtest.a: libtest.lst $(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)
        ar -rcs $@ $(filter-out $<,$?)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to sort both file lists to get a deterministic result?  That is: the contents of `libtest.lst` could be sorted when created or, failing that, when used; and the current content of library should be sorted when creating `$@.contents`.  Otherwise, newly added/updated files will be at the end of the archive output, but not in the canonical list of files in the archive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Almost certainly. I thought of that as I was writing it and thought about adding a comment to that effect (I wasn't sure I wanted to put it in the code directly for fear of it complicating things and because ultimately I think putting that logic in the `libtest.lst` recipe is a better idea).

Comment: IMO, the 1st version results in regenerating `.a` on each run, which is rather undesirable. Only your 2nd improved version is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question and Etan already gave an answer. I tried to solve it like Etan but with "more make" and "less bash":

```
LibSources = $(wildcard *.c)
LibObjects = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(LibSources))

Lib := libtest.a

LibContent  = $(if $(wildcard $(Lib)),$(shell ar t $(Lib) | grep -v "^__"),)
LibRemoves  = $(filter-out $(LibObjects),$(LibContent))
SrcRemoves  = $(patsubst %.o,%.c,$(LibRemoves))
ArDelete    = $(if $(LibRemoves),ar d $(Lib) $(LibRemoves),)

.PHONY: all clean

all:    $(Lib)

clean:
        $(RM) $(Lib)

$(Lib)(%.o) : %.o
        ar cr $@ $^

$(SrcRemoves) :
        $(ArDelete)

$(Lib) : $(Lib)($(LibObjects)) $(SrcRemoves)
        ranlib $(Lib)
```

Note that this uses the implicit rule for creating object files.

[BSD ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) creates members like `__.SYMDEF` for the global symbol table. The `-grep -v` is used to filter out this member.

### A bit more details

```
LibSources = $(wildcard *.c)
```

would expand in your case to a.c b.c c.c or what ever files with extensions `.c` you have.

```
LibObjects = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(LibSources))
```

gives the list of object files that *should* be in the library. For example. `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o`.

```
LibContent  = $(if $(wildcard $(Lib)),$(shell ar t $(Lib) | grep -v "^__"),)
```

If the library already exists this gives a list of archived object files. The entry `__.SYMDEF SORTED` for the index needs to be filtered out.

```
LibRemoves  = $(filter-out $(LibObjects),$(LibContent))
```

That gives the difference, i.e. the list of object files to delete. And

```
SrcRemoves  = $(patsubst %.o,%.c,$(LibRemoves))
```

therefore expands to the list of source files that were removed.

```
ArDelete    = $(if $(LibRemoves),ar d $(Lib) $(LibRemoves),)
```

If nothing needs to be deleted it expands to an empty string, otherwise to the command `ar d libtest.a ...objects-to-delete...`

The prerequisites for the library are: all objects are members of the archive, and objects are removed if a source file was removed. In case the library was modified the index gets updated:

```
$(Lib) : $(Lib)($(LibObjects)) $(SrcRemoves)
        ranlib $(Lib)
```

GNU make supports rules for [archive members](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Archive-Members.html#Archive-Members).  If an object file is not a member of the archive it gets added:

```
$(Lib)(%.o) : %.o
        ar cr $@ $^
```

If source files were deleted (or renamed) the corresponding object files get deleted in the archive

```
$(SrcRemoves) :
        $(ArDelete)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another robust way is to make all your object files, archives, shared libraries and executables depend on `Makefile` that builds them. In recipes you `$(filter-out Makefile,$^)` to filter out `Makefile` from compiler, ar and linker command lines. That works best with [non-recursive makefiles](http://www.real-linux.org.uk/recursivemake.pdf).

This way whenever you change your `Makefile` it rebuilds and relinks automatically. An ideal way would be to rebuild only if compiler options changed. It is possible but requires a bit of extra effort that may not be worth it  (`ninja` does that automatically, but since `ninja` build files are normally generated by a higher level build system, like `CMake`, that feature is almost pointless).

Also, if you do not distribute `.a` files, you may like to use *thin* archives with `T` [`ar`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html) option to avoid needless copying of object files into the archive.

> GNU `ar` can optionally create a *thin* archive, which contains a symbol index and references to the original copies of the member files of the archive. This is useful for building libraries for use within a local build tree, where the relocatable objects are expected to remain available, and copying the contents of each object would only waste time and space.