# How to avoid a clean compile after removing a compilation unit?

Tags: c++, cmake

I removed a few files (Spring.cpp / Spring.h) from my project (no longer referenced anywhere). But running `make` complains that those files are missing.

```cpp
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Workspace/newgame/sandbox/src/components/Spring.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
make[2]: *** [sandbox/CMakeFiles/game.dir/src/components/Spring.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sandbox/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all] Error 2
```

running `cmake ..` and then `make` fixes this. but regenerating takes forever. There has to be a better way

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614163/automatically-remove-files-from-static-library

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a clean build?  Do you need compilation or linking errors?

Comment: It is the best way and it shouldn't take forever. So you need to find out why it takes forever and fix it.